# when I run this code below, it doesn’t give me True or False

Tags: python, list, using

it doesn’t give an output
and I Know that the output should be True or False

```
some = [1, 9, 21, 3]
9 in some
```

Comment: **how** do you run this code? Maybe you want `print(9 in some)`?

Comment: You have to print the result. print(9 in some)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you need to do something with the result. You can save it into a variable with:

```py
var = 9 in some
```

or print it directly with:

```py
print(9 in some)
```

Answer (score -2):

It *does* return a TRUE/FALSE:

```
[In]: 3 in list([1,2,35])
[Out]: False 

[In]: 3 in list([1,2,3,5])
[Out]: True
```

From the documentation:

> "The operators *in* and *not in* test for membership. x in s evaluates
> to True if x is a member of s, and False otherwise. x not in s returns
> the negation of x in s. All built-in sequences and set types support
> this as well as dictionary, for which in tests whether the dictionary
> has a given key." [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations)

Comment: Your example occurs only if it is typed in an IPython cell (a unique cell or in the last row of the cell). And of course, the result is also displayed without using print if typed directly into the console.

Comment: @Marco, yes I am using iPython, regardless Membership test operations return a boolean: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations

Comment: Right. Of course it returns that expected output, but only if typed into a console or IPython (under the conditions I described earlier).

Comment: @Marco  I'm missing your point--it is not like the console is "lying."  `in`, like the docs  state,  evaluates the list and returns a boolean.  Assign `9 in some` to a variable and check its type if you don't believe me.

Comment: You're saying things I haven't said at any time. I'm saying that the result is displayed only if the code runs in the console or in IPython (under the conditions I've described). If it is executed in a .py script, it will be necessary to use print for the output to be displayed.

Comment: When I said "expected output" I meant the display of the output, not the result expected to come out.